# Is it possible to embed a powerBI application (not report!) in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, powerbi

I'm currently embedding various powerBI reports in a reactjs intranet app using [powerbi-client-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/powerbi-client-react). However, our data analyst asked if I can embed the entire reporting application, so that all reports within the app are available to an authenticated user, since then he won't have to maintain access controls for each report and can simply allow any users in our domain to access the app.

I have been searching but haven't found anything addressing this use case-- everything assumes that the goal is to embed a single report rather than an entire reporting app. Is it possible to embed an entire app?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not supported. As you can see from the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/powerbi-client-react), applications are not supported:

> The React library lets you embed the following Power BI items:
>
> - Reports
> - Dashboards
> - Dashboard tiles
> - Report visuals
> - Q&A